# Why do I need an else statement in this backword string recursion?

Tags: loops, recursion

In the below problem, I originally didn't have the else brackets and thought the code would run fine. In my mind, if I have code outside of the "if statement", it would automatically default to "else." However, the code only worked and ran properly when I DID have the else brackets.

Can someone explain why the else brackets are needed?

```
    function backwardString(string) {

        if( string.length === 1 ) {
            // base case  
            console.log (string)
        }
        else {
            // recursion itself 
    
            console.log(string[string.length-1]) 
    
            //call the function again()
//          console.log( string.substring( 0,string.length - 1 ) )
            backwardString( string.substring( 0, string.length - 1 ) )
        }
    }
    
    backwardString('happy');
    // y
    // p
    // p
    // a
    // h
```

Comment: "In my mind, if I have code outside of the "if statement", it would automatically default to "else." - that's not how `if` works. I think you're thinking of when there's a `return` statement inside an `if` branch.

Comment: Think: if you don't have an `else`, where does execution flow to after the base case code runs?

Comment: @Dai, yes you're right... that is what I was thinking of, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function where we `return` and thus we force the control flow:

```
function fac(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * fac(n - 1); 
}
```

So the code will start on top and go statement to statement. With a recursive function there is **no difference**. When the recursive function get called all bound and local variables are unique to that call and the callee waits in the same manner as if it called a completely unique non recursive function. A recursive function that works will hit a base case and then it will go back to the calee. If you have an extra line of code outside the if **both the base case and default case will evaluate it once the if is done**.

In this example code1 and code4 is always called regardless what `test` is and you call either `code2` og `code3` depending on the expression `test` being truthy or not.

```
code1()
if (test) {
  code2()
} else {
  code3()
}
code44();
```

Comment: okay, this helped me in understanding it. Thank you!